# How can I use a nonstandard color for the UIScrollView indicator?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

The UI gives [3 options for UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle), but I want to make the UIScrollView indicator red, which is not one of the standard styles.

Can I do this?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

### YES!! you can

> Both UIScrollView indicator are sub view of UIScrollView. So, we can
>   access subview of UIScrollView and change the property of subview.

**1 .Add UIScrollViewDelegate**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

**2. Add scrollViewDidScroll in implementation section**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
    //get refrence of vertical indicator
    UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
    //set color to vertical indicator
    [verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    //get refrence of horizontal indicator
    UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
    //set color to horizontal indicator
    [horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

> Note:- Because these indicator update every time when you scroll
>   (means reset to default). SO, we put this code in scrollViewDidScroll
>   delegate method.

[image]
**[Demo available on GitHub - https://github.com/ioshacks/UIScrollViewIndicatorColor](https://github.com/ioshacks/UIScrollViewIndicatorColor)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure not the answer you want, but you could put a uiview(for the scroll indicator) over the top of the scrollview then add a delegate to listen for when your scrollview is scrolled, then update the position of the uiview